# Database won't store correct timezone

Tags: php, postgresql, timezone, lumen, php-carbon

I'm trying to save a record, which date using specific timezone.

1. The date is on carbon format.
2. The database is using postgresql 11, with datatype `timestamp_with_timezone`
3. the `APP_TIMEZONE` was set to `UTC` on the `.env`.

here is the dump of `$record` **before** `$record->save()`

```
"started_at" => Carbon @1583895600 {#920
  date: 2020-03-11 10:00:00.0 Asia/Bangkok (+07:00)
}
"finished_at" => Carbon @1584104400 {#2112
  date: 2020-03-13 20:00:00.0 Asia/Bangkok (+07:00)
}
```

here is what inside the query log after saving

```
0 => Carbon @1583895600 {#920
  date: 2020-03-11 10:00:00.0 Asia/Bangkok (+07:00)
}
1 => Carbon @1584104400 {#2112
  date: 2020-03-13 20:00:00.0 Asia/Bangkok (+07:00)
}
```

and here is the dump of `Model::find($record->id)`

```
"started_at" => "2020-03-11 10:00:00-07"
"finished_at" => "2020-03-13 20:00:00-07"
```

It has become minus instead of plus, and I don't know what causes this. I tried to save the date with a string instead of Carbon which is `2020-03-11 10:00:00 +07:00` but it produces exactly same result.
And what makes it worse that it **happens randomly**. It works fine on my laptop, staging server, but not on some of my coworker's laptop, and production server. I have confirmed that every one are using the same environment.

What might be the cause?

Comment: Debug the ->save method and see what exact SQL is it sending to the database. It can be done on php side or on database side.

Comment: @filiprem query log shows exact carbon object (with +07:00) inserted into table

Comment: If database column has "with timezone" data type and the INSERT statement has the TZ included, then most probably  database is correct and your problem must be in somewhere in the application model interpreting db data incorrectly.

Comment: nevermind, I just know that postgre does not store timezone on its timezone-aware datatype. reference: http://blog.untrod.com/2016/08/actually-understanding-timezones-in-postgresql.html